# This hermitian operator seems to have complex eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

It is easy to show that [a hermitian operator must have real eigenvalues](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Hermitian_Operators_have_Real_Eigenvalues).

It is also easy to show that [the operator $-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is hermitian](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node144.html).

But from a computational perspective, I feel like it is possible to just propose working counter-examples. Specifically, the following eigenvector problem, 
$$
-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x) = \lambda f(x)
$$

appears to be solved by $f(x) = e^{-3x}$ with $\lambda = 3i \not\in \mathbb{R}$. We can verify by substitution:
\begin{align}
-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{-3x} &= 3ie^{-3x}\\
\\
3ie^{-3x} &= 3ie^{-3x}
\end{align}

This imaginary eigenvalue contradicts the proofs I linked to. I must be doing something illogical here, or misunderstanding the proofs.

Comment: What space is this operator acting on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What an operator is depends on which space it is defined on. Your link shows that $-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is Hermitian on $L^2$, $e^{-3x}$  is not in $L^2$, so it is not a counterexample. Doing this naively one can find an "eigenvector" of $-i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$ for any complex number as an eigenvalue, namely $e^{ax}$ with a suitable $a$.